# How to resolve error ng-snotify has an incomptible peer dependency before updating to angular 9 from 8?

Tags: angular, incompatibility

I am working to update angular 6 app to angular 9 using [this guid](https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=8.0-9.1)e, step by step from 6 to 7 to 8 to 9.

Now I just have to update v8 to v9 but I had some issues with peer dependencies. I had to use force in my angular update, and this is the second try and I hope I do it this time without using --force.

```
ng update @angular/core@9 @angular/cli@9 --force
```

[ng-snotify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-snotify/v/9.0.1) document was not helpful for showing required version pre angular version, even versions like 7.0 and 8.0.0 where not registered when I tried to do

**How to fix ng-snotify peer dependency before updating to angular 9?**

```
  ng update ng-snotify@8.0.0
```

for example!

[image]

[image]

PS C:\Users\Salma\source\Zippyyum\Zippyyum_DCOrdering-Web> ng update @angular/core@9 @angular/cli@9 --force
The installed local Angular CLI version is older than the latest stable version.
Installing a temporary version to perform the update.
Installing packages for tooling via npm.
Installed packages for tooling via npm.
Using package manager: 'npm'
Collecting installed dependencies...
Found 53 dependencies.
Fetching dependency metadata from registry...
Package "ng-snotify" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/core" (requires "^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0" (extended), would install "9.1.13").
Package "ng-snotify" has an incompatible peer dependency to "zone.js" (requires "^0.8.4", would install "0.10.3").

I had to use --force when upgrading to 9, ng-snotify packages are not all found and does not clearly specify what version is compatible with angular versions.

**Any idea how to resolve that ng-snotify and update without using --force?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used force to update to Angular 9, but then after that I updated the package with

```
ng update ng-snotify
```

[image]

then cleaning node modules,
then `npm install`
then `npm start`
and it worked[image]